# Como puedo pasar una variable dentro de un body

Tags: flutter, dart, context

tengo un servicio que me trae la dirección del cliente seleccionado de la base de datos. Tal y como está confeccionado el SOAP para que te traiga la información en el body tienes que pasarle el "Codigo" del cliente y ese "Codigo" no lo se hasta que no hago click en su nombre, que es cuando me lo retorna ya que tengo 600 registros.

Mi duda es como puedo pasarle en una variable dicho codigo.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:jpaSOAP/models/models.dart';
import 'package:jpaSOAP/services/services.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:xml2json/xml2json.dart';

class DirectionService extends ChangeNotifier {
  final _baseUrl = Uri.parse('http://xxx.asmx');
  final _body = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <soap12:Body>
          <SociedadDireccion_Lee xmlns="http://xxx.org/">
            <usuario>usuario</usuario>
            <password>contraseña</password>
            <Codigo>112</Codigo> //aqui deberia de poner el codigo
          </SociedadDireccion_Lee>
        </soap12:Body>
      </soap12:Envelope>''';

  final direction = [];
  Direction? selectedDirection;

  bool isLoading = true;

  DirectionService() {
    this.loadDirections();
  }

  Future<List> loadDirections() async {
    this.isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    final resp = await http.post(
      _baseUrl,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        "SOAPAction": "http://xxxxx"
      },
      body: _body,
    );

    Xml2Json xml2json = Xml2Json();
    xml2json.parse(resp.body);
    final jsondata = xml2json.toParker();
    final data = json.decode(jsondata);

    final datos = data['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']
        ['SociedadDireccion_LeeResponse']['SociedadDireccion_LeeResult'];

    this.direction.add(datos);

    this.isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();

    return direction;
  }
}
```

Aqui tengo la pagina de clientes, donde al hacer click veo con el print el codigo que tiene, pero no se llevarmelo al servicio de antes porque he probado poniendo un Widget(BuildContext Context) para llevar el Provider pero al ponerlo me saltan muchos errores.
No se si me explico bien o no.

```
import 'package:jpaSOAP/pages/pages.dart';
import 'package:jpaSOAP/search/search_delegate.dart';
import 'package:jpaSOAP/services/services.dart';
import 'package:jpaSOAP/widgets/clients_list.dart';
import 'package:jpaSOAP/widgets/widgets.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ClientesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static String routeName = 'clientes';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final clientService = Provider.of<ClientsService>(context);
    final directionService = Provider.of<DirectionService>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(63, 63, 156, 1),
        elevation: 0,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () =>
                showSearch(context: context, delegate: ClienteSearchDelegate()),
            icon: Icon(Icons.search_outlined),
          ),
        ],
        title: const Text('Clientes'),
      ),
      drawer: const MenuWidget(),
      body: AppBackground(
        child: Scrollbar(
          isAlwaysShown: true,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: clientService.clients.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                clientService.selectedClient =
                    clientService.clients[index].copy();
                directionService.selectedDirection =
                    directionService.selectedDirection;

                print(clientService.selectedClient.sociedad!.codigo);

                Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'cliente');
              },
              child: ClientsList(
                clients: clientService.clients[index],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

En la pagina de clientes, cuando tengo el listado de todos los clientes y pulso sobre uno de ellos me abre otra pagina con la informacion detallada de ese cliente, el problema que me encuentro es que tal y como está planteado el SOAP en el body le tengo que pasar el codigo del cliente, como me respondieron con el metodo getBody lo podria hacer pero me lanza el error "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0"

Os paso el codigo de la pagina clientes a ver si estoy poniendo algo mal.

```
class ClientesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static String routeName = 'clientes';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final clientService = Provider.of<ClientsService>(context);
    final directionService =
        Provider.of<DirectionService>(context, listen: false);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(63, 63, 156, 1),
        elevation: 0,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () =>
                showSearch(context: context, delegate: ClienteSearchDelegate()),
            icon: Icon(Icons.search_outlined),
          ),
        ],
        title: const Text('Clientes'),
      ),
      drawer: const MenuWidget(),
      body: AppBackground(
        child: Scrollbar(
          isAlwaysShown: true,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: clientService.clients.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                clientService.selectedClient =
                    clientService.clients[index].copy();
                directionService.selectedDirection =
                    directionService.direction[0].copy();

                print(clientService.selectedClient.sociedad!.codigo);

                String codigo = clientService.selectedClient.sociedad!.codigo;

                Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'cliente');
              },
              child: ClientsList(
                clients: clientService.clients[index],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar un método en lugar de una variable, donde recibas como parámetro el código.

En lugar de:

```dart
final _body = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <soap12:Body>
          <SociedadDireccion_Lee xmlns="http://xxx.org/">
            <usuario>usuario</usuario>
            <password>contraseña</password>
            <Codigo>112</Codigo> //aqui deberia de poner el codigo
          </SociedadDireccion_Lee>
        </soap12:Body>
      </soap12:Envelope>''';
```

Tendrías esto:

```dart
String getBody(String codigo) => '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <soap12:Body>
          <SociedadDireccion_Lee xmlns="http://xxx.org/">
            <usuario>usuario</usuario>
            <password>contraseña</password>
            <Codigo>$codigo</Codigo>
          </SociedadDireccion_Lee>
        </soap12:Body>
      </soap12:Envelope>''';
```

Y lo llamarías:

```dart
  final resp = await http.post(
      _baseUrl,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        "SOAPAction": "http://xxxxx"
      },
      body: getBody('codigo_aquí'),
    );
```

UPDATE

Para pasar argumentos con rutas nombradas, puedes hacerlo así :

```dart
 Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      'cliente',
      arguments: codigo,
    );
```

Link: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta, pero me encuentro con un problema que a lo mejor no me explique bien, voy a editar mi pregunta para añadirlo.

Comment: actualicé mi respuesta para que veas lo de pasar argumentos entre rutas

Comment: Gracias @diegoveloper pero creo que estoy muy liado, yo tengo un listado de clientes que vienen de una peticion rest, cuando hago click en un cliente para ver sus detalles, debo de hacer otra peticion rest a otra dirección y un parametro del body para que pueda responderme es el codigo. El tema es que me da error porque cuando hago click parece como si no pasase por el servicio para hacer la peticion y me devuelve un error "RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty". La verdad que soy muy novato y no se si me explico bien.